# Multiple link-only answers used to justify another

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

Ran across a review in the LQP Queue. It's for this question

[how to use CRUD in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960189/how-to-use-crud-in-wordpress)

Got stumped a bit because of the following

- It's not asking for a third party tool so can't close it for off-topic (might be too broad so could be closable that way but it's iffy)
- Everyone who responded gave a link to a third party tool

So the answerer in [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12046808) gives this response to someone who criticized it for being link-only (emphasis mine)

> thanks for your comments, I knew about this rule, **but if you can see all previous answers are also with link**. For my post I added a video tutorial which is length about 4 minutes and link where all process generating by website itself. So there are no options to describe all process and if is these links will not work so this answer will not have any meaning.

So should the answer be deleted? Should it just be closed? Or is there some way to salvage this?

Comment: For more context, this is the link to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36674780/1743880. (And my opinion: It's not because they're doing it wrong that you should do the same)

Comment: Frankly, the question and answers should be nuked from orbit... *it's the only way to be sure*.

Comment: Most of the links are on the first page of Google if you just search the question title.

Comment: The question is now locked with a "visit meta" post notice, but it there's no link to this meta question.  Maybe a mod should add one as a comment?

Comment: *Burn it with fire*...seriously the first and accepted answer should be flagged for deletion I'd say. It's going to get terrible link rot (ointments available from your nearest pharmacists)

Comment: If it were up to me, all php related questions should be closed as spam and as an offense to actual/serious programmers. In this particular case I'd settle for a 'close as too broad', since the question is the opposite of specific.

Comment: well, half the world is very happy it's completely not up to you @konqi

Comment: @konqi we have been trying to convince the SO team to close all (including new posted ones) PHP questions by default for a while now. Sadly as of now it's still not implemented.

Comment: @PeeHaa Well, they tried; but the filter engine was written in php.

Comment: "how to use CRUD in wordpress" Yeah, definitely too broad. That also explains why all the answers are just links. A decent answer to that question could easily be multiple pages long, or could be a library with associated documentation on how to use it.